# Is it correct if i am using await + ToListAsync() over IQueryable which is not defined as a task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await, entity-framework-6

I am using asp.net MVC-5 with EF-6, and I am not sure if using await + `ToListAsync` is valid. For example, I have the following repository method which returns an IQueryable :-

```
public IQueryable<TSet> getAllScanEmailTo()
{
    return t.TSets.Where(a=>a.Name.StartsWith("ScanEmail"));    
}
```

And I am calling it as follow:-

```
var emailsTo = await repository.getAllScanEmailTo().ToListAsync();
```

In the beginning, I thought I will get an error because I am using "await" a method which is not defined as a task, but the above worked well, so can anyone advice on this, please ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> At the beginning I thought I will get an error because I am using
> "await" a method which is not defined as a task, but the above worked
> well

Actually, *you are* awaiting a method which returns a `Task<T>`, where `T` is a `List<TSet>`. If you look at the extension method [`QueryableExtensions.ToListAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.tolistasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0), you'll see that it returns a `Task<List<TSource>>`. You are asynchronously waiting on this method to query the database, create the list and return it back to the caller. When you `await` on such a method, the method won't return until the operation has completed. *async-await* makes your code feel synchronous, while execution is actually asynchronous.

Comment: Good & complete explanation.

Comment: @Yuval of i am already aware of this ,, but usually i use await over a Task,, and all the method chain inside my code will be Task + await.. but since i can not wrap the IQueryable with a Task so i did it in this way ,, i am using IQueryable --> await .tolistasync() ... so will this code works as-if the IQueryable is wrapped inside a Task?. so in my case the iis thread will be released till the tolistasync() complete execution , as normal await works ?

Comment: @johnG Yes. The thread will be released while the query executes, and returned once the it finishes.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov so even if i am not wrapping the  IQurable inside a Task (becuase i can not do so) , this will still behave as-if the IQurable is wrapped inside a task , so the normal await + Task will still apply here?

Comment: @johnG Yup, it will. No need to wrap this in a `Task` yourself, that will be of no-use.

Comment: but if i am returning an entity such as "public Employee getEmployee()" instead of IQueryable then wrapping the method inside a task is a must ? is this correct ? but for IQueryable i do not need to do so , since IQueryable is just a way to build the query that will be used later,, is this correct ?

Comment: @johnG If your method executes synchronously, and returns an `Employee`, then you can't run it asynchronously, because the API itself is synchronous.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov but if i use SingleOrDefualtAsync then i can get  single employee async ? is this correct ?

Answer (score 19):

Actually there is no problem because you are awating the `ToListAsync()` not the `getAllScanEmailTo()`.

**EDIT:** To see how async-await pattern is working you can see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Here is a usefull image from there

[image]

Comment: so is my approach valid ? or doing so will suspend execution until the ToListAsync() method of the IQueryable<TSet> completes.

Comment: yes i know this execution path very well, but my original question was how will await + Iqurable works together. since i can not wrap an IQueryable inside a task.. so i am using await + ToListAsync() but over a non-task method, so will this have any side-effect,, or my code will work as-if I have wrapped the IQueryable inside a Task ?? did u get my point ?

Answer (score 4):

You are not "awaiting a method". You are **awaiting a `Task`**, which is an awaitable.

You call `getAllScanEmailTo` that returns an `IQueryable<TSet>` on which you then call `ToListAsync` which returns the `Task<List<TSet>>` you are awaiting.

Comment: so using IQuerable with await as i am doing is valid ? or doing so will suspend execution until the ToListAsync() method of the IQueryable<TSet> completes.

Comment: @johnG yes. You are awaiting the `Task`, not the `IQueryable`. And yes, you will wait for `ToListAsync` to complete.

Comment: but is doing so will suspend execution until the ToListAsync() method of the IQueryable<TSet> completes ??

Comment: @johnG yes. await will asynchronously wait for the operation to complete.

Comment: yes i know ,, but here i am asking if the IIS thread will say occupied till the method is completed ? or it will be released during the method execution ?

Comment: @johnG no. When you await an asynchronous operation the thread is released.

Comment: so can i say for this scenario i can assume that the IQuerable is wrapped inside a Task ? so in this case nothing really matter if the iQuerable is not being wrapped inside a Task , this was my original question?